# Spring MVC Controller refer to string in property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I was having some problem when trying to access the key value pairs in properties file using Spring MVC.

Here is where I stored the properties file: `../common/properties/AppResource.properties`.

An example of key value pair in the file:

```
error.password.mismatch=Invalid userid and/or password, please try again
```

In my servlet.xml, I declared the following bean:

```
<bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
<property name="basename"> 
    <value>classpath*:common/properties/*.properties</value> 
</property>
```

In my controller, I am trying to access the key value pair:

```
} catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
    model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "error.password.mismatch");
    return "login";
}
```

In my JSP page, I am printing the error message:

```
<font class="errorClass"><form:errors path="errorMessage" /></font>
```

However, the message printed out was "error.password.mismatch" instead of referring to the text in properties file. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding an attribute `errorMessage` in the model should not work with `<form:errors path="errorMessage"/>`. Share the validation part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `path` attribute of `<form:errors/>` denotes the field that you want to show error for. You will need to register a field error against that field.

If you are using custom [`Validator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html),

```java
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    // your logic here
    errors.rejectValue("fieldName", "error.password.mismatch");
}
```

And in JSP:

```
<form:errors path="fieldName"/>
```

**NOTE:**

If you want to show message in a different manner other than using `<form:errors/>` tag,

You can do

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:message key="error.password.mismatch"/>
```

**Or**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<s:message code="error.password.mismatch"/>
```

**Or**

If you want to resolve the value from controller, you can use [`MessageSourceAccessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/MessageSourceAccessor.html).

```xml
<bean id="messageSourceAccessor" class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
```

In controller:

```java
@Autowired
private MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor;
```

and

```java
model.addAttribute("someMessage", messageSourceAccessor.getMessage("error.password.mismatch"));
```

and in JSP:

```
<c:out value="${someMessage}"/>
```

Answering to OP's comment:

> If I used the MessageSourceAccesor, where do I declare the path for
>   property files?

From [Spring Framework Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-messagesource):

> ```xml
> <beans>
>     <bean id="messageSource"
>             class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
>         <property name="basenames">
>             <list>
>                 <value>format</value>
>                 <value>exceptions</value>
>                 <value>windows</value>
>             </list>
>         </property>
>     </bean>
> </beans>
> ```
>
> The example assumes that you have three resource bundles called
>   `format`, `exceptions` and `windows` defined in your classpath.

Comment: If I used the MessageSourceAccesor, where do I declare the path for property files?

Comment: Updated the answer with reply to this question.

Comment: Thanks! But lets say my property files nested under common/properties/xxx.properties, I just put as <value>properties</value> will do?

Comment: Where is `common/*` located in? And it should be `<value>xxx</value>`.

Comment: it is under src/sc/project/common/properties/xxx.properties

Comment: You should put the `properties` files in `/src/main/resources/`, so that they are added to the root of your classpath.

Comment: I see I see thanks so much! So all my xml files should be put under the resources folder as well?